# AutoSys Job re-run with fixed delay

Tags: autosys

I need autosys to rerun my job in case of failure N number of times with a fixed delay between re-runs, i.e. Autosys should wait for 10 minutes before re-running the job.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: it possible but have you tried any configuration for Autosys Job?

Comment: I need the configuration for this requirement. I am not familiar with Autosys. My autosys guy says the re tries is possible but the delay is not possible to configure.

Comment: check below configuration for jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by using two Autosys jobs mentioned as below.  shown only specific configurations as other configurations should be as per your environment and execution need.

Job 1 :

```
sample jil code / Writing jil code:

insert_job: job1
job_type: c
permission: gx,ge,wx,we,mx,me
days_of_week: all
description: “description field”
n_retrys: 10  // Number of failure
term_run_time: 60
profile: /tmp/.profile
```

Job 2 :

```
insert_job : job12
command: sleep 300  // specify your time duration in seconds
condition: failure(job1)
```

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve without having two jobs? I was thinking based on a return status from the job is autosys not smart enough to rerun the job after waiting for say 10 mins?

Comment: How does the control passed back to the first job? It fails, the second job waits, but the first one will start independently from the second one.